# macOS 10.14/10.15 3rd party applications do not start

Tags: network, applications, catalina, internet, 3rd-party

3rd party applications do not start. The computer does not have an internet connection by default, but only to the local network. When the connection to the Internet is established, all the applications I wanted to start in the dock start immediately. You can see this in the video at about 27 seconds, all applications start immediately. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

[Video about this issue](https://youtu.be/ru583ckpVwI)

Comment: Maybe their trying to ping their servers since they think you have internet but can’t?